# Thread hangs when creating ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, stream

I've got the following code on my **server** end:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread
{
Socket clientSocket;

DataInputStream dis;
ObjectInputStream ois;
DataOutputStream dos;

public ClientThread(Socket acceptedSocket)
{
    clientSocket = acceptedSocket;

    try
    {
        dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); // HANGS HERE
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ClientThread " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Rest of the class omitted**

Why does my application freeze when calling the socket inputstream twice, without throwing an exception?

<strike>Yes, I could just save the inputstream to an InputStream variable and use that variable to get the desired inputstream type, but I'm curious to why it hangs when being called twice from the socket?</strike>

What's the difference? Being called twice doesn't change anything?

---

**EDIT:**  Even when saving the inputstream to an InputStream variable and using that variable to get the desired inputstream (DataInputStream and ObjectInputStream) it still hangs when called more than once?

Example:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread
{
Socket clientSocket;

InputStream is;
DataInputStream dis;
ObjectInputStream ois;
DataOutputStream dos;

public ClientThread(Socket acceptedSocket)
{
    clientSocket = acceptedSocket;

    try
    {
        is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is); // STILL HANGS HERE
        dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ClientThread " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Rest of the class omitted**

---

**Client-side code**:

```
public class LoginLogic_Callable implements Callable<String>
{
Socket socket;
String actionString;
String username;
String password;

public LoginLogic_Callable(Socket sentSocket, String sentUsername, String sentPassword)
{
    socket = sentSocket;
    username = sentUsername;
    password = sentPassword;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception 
{
    String userLoginStatus = null;

    try
    {
        DataOutputStream loginUserData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        String[] loginUserInfo = new String[2];

        loginUserInfo[0] = username;
        loginUserInfo[1] = password;

        loginUserData.writeUTF("userlogin");
        oos.writeObject(loginUserInfo);
        loginUserData.flush();
        oos.flush();

        userLoginStatus = dis.readUTF();

        loginUserData.close();
        oos.close();
        dis.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }   

    return userLoginStatus;
}
}
```

Comment: I know in android stuffs hang sometimes but using asynctask solves it. Dunno the name of the asyncTask in java. I guess thats not the thing but just a comment.

Comment: Re your edit, you don't appear to have read my answer. Please post the relevant client code too.

Comment: Client-side code added.

Comment: OK, now see edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just calling `getInputStream()` isn't 'reading', and it doesn't cause this problem. You can prove that by calling it ten times, or constructing ten `DataInputStreams` round it. It is the construction of the `ObjectInputStream` that is causing the problem, and you can prove *that* by removing the `DataInputStream` altogether, which you should do anyway: see below.

You're creating an `ObjectInputStream`. The constructor of `ObjectInputStream` reads a stream header that is written by the constructor of `ObjectOutputStream`. As that isn't happening in this code, and presumably not at the peer either, it blocks forever.

For the same reason, you must create the `ObjectOutputStream` first, before the `ObjectInputStream`, otherwise again you will have a deadlock.

There seems to be some plan here to use two kinds of stream on the same socket. Don't do that. It won't work, and it isn't necessary, as the object streams have all the same methods as the data streams, in addition to the object reading and writing methods.

**EDIT** Now that you've posted your client code, what is happening is that the client is deferring creation of the `ObjectOutputStream` until `call()` is called. It should be created in the constructor of that class. Otherwise your server side constructor blocks until `call()` is called at the client. And you still need to get rid of the redundant streams.

Comment: That doesn't make sense... So you're saying that I'm forced to create an ObjectOutputStream before I create the ObjectInputStream, even though I will never use the ObjectOutputStream in this case..

Comment: @Birdman if you will never use the ObjectOutputStream then when do you plan to use the ObjectInputStream? You cant recieve objects in your input stream without the output stream sending them.

Comment: The client (Peer) DOES have an ObjectOutputStream, the server (Which is the case here) has an ObjectInputStream to receive the object. What's wrong then?

Comment: Not only does it make sense, it is documented in the Javadoc. If the peer is creating an ObjectOutputStream, it must be doing so *after* creating its ObjectInputStream, which causes a deadlock, as I said above.

Comment: @Alex That doesn't follow. You can send objects in a single direction only, or in both directions.

Comment: but you cant receive objects which haven't been sent. If the server never sends objects to the client then it wont receive any.

Comment: @Alex Of course not, but that doesn't imply that this code need both streams.

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that, just that to send and receive objects in one direction you need an output stream on the sending end and an input stream at the receiving end.

Comment: @Alex I imagine so, but it isn't clear from what you actually said.